# Using Blender to animate Enviroment Interaction. specifically buttons

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender, modeling

I am trying to make a desk with buttons that can be animated in unity.
Now, I have managed to get the keyframes and such to my liking.
Its just when I import the .blend file, I just get a "Default Take" Animation file with all the keyframes for each button.

When played, it pushes all the buttons.

All the animations key frames are the same (The Buttons are a child of an ojbject, so its relative/location based), so is it possible to just apply one keyframe set to any button I desire?

here is the blend file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38204535/Control%20Panel.blend

I only did start 3d modeling/animating this week, So if there is something really odd in the project, feel free to give your opinion on it!

TL;DR How Do I animate Buttons For unity?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run animations independently, you want save animation of each button in a different take and different button.

Also, take a look at [unity animation system](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation). It looks really close to how animation in Blender and other animation packages work, but can be easier and closer integrated to unity code, even run some callbacks in code on certain keyframes.

Comment: How would I save them in different takes?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183/how-can-i-manage-multiple-animations-in-one-blend-file

Comment: I have them set as actions already. It still  just spits out one animation file. Maybe  I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Are you sure your import settings are correct? Manual can help: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationsImport.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FBXImporter-Animations.html

Comment: Alright, to my knowledge I have set up the actions as I should in blender.
But in unity I can only get a animation file called "default take" with several different timelines in it. I cant find a way to seperate them into their own actions.